# android studio library of ftp fail to import

Tags: android, ftp

After i put commons-net3.3 into libs, but i still cannot import

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
```

is there any step i have missed?

Answer (score 5):

Just add into gradle

```
 dependencies {
    implementation 'org.kie.modules:org-apache-commons-net:6.5.0.Final'
}
```

Comment: this worked for me i added this onto the MODULE build.gradle and then added the imports to my *.java class for my app, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

i solved in this way:
copy commons-net-3.3.jar in libs folder of you app, after
Open File->ProjectStructure->Dependencies, on bottom plus button add "File dependency" and select the library.
Now you should be able to import library class in your activity.java properly