# Many troubles importing a library into AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

So I'd like to import the "apache commons ftp" libraries for use in my project.  I got as far as the importing the modules, and am including a pic just to show that they're in there.

But when I try to use the import statements

```
(i.e.) import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
```

they fail.

So am curious if I am missing a step, or am missing something.

[image]

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334876/android-studio-library-of-ftp-fail-to-import) might help you

Comment: It did and thanks.  How do I mark this with the green check?

Comment: you cannot, its comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Please add below dependency in your gradle:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net
compile group: 'commons-net', name: 'commons-net', version: '3.5'
```

For any dependency to import in Android Studio through gradle use below reference:

https://mvnrepository.com/

This will save your time from importing module and solving gradle errors :)

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand AndiGeeky's answer if you don't modify so you have a custom library.

Meanwhile if you really want to use the library as a module, you can add this line in your ***build.gradle*** in your *module app*

```
    compile project(':NAME_OF_YOUR_MODULE')           << should be commons-net-3.5
```

Hope that will help you :)

Comment: If I do it this way, via text in the gradle:

* Do I no longer need to do that whole import wizard thing? and 

* Is there a pro v. con reason to do it one way over another?   

Thanks